# how to default select a value - html select inside <apex:repeat>

Tags: picklist, html, repeat

After record creation, if the record is edited I want to auto-populate picklist value which is dynamic and I have a value which am passing it in apex:repeat

```
<select Class="slds-input form-control">
    <apex:repeat value="{!updateObj.MFF_RelatedFldval}" var="pickOpts"  >
        <option value="{!pickOpts.value}" >{!pickOpts.label}</option> //Account,contact,case
    </apex:repeat>
</select>
```

I want the `{!updatePicklstFldValsMap[updateObj.MFF_FieldName]} //contact`  value to be selected in the picklist.

Specified the below statement after apex:repaeat which added two same  values in the picklist (Contact)

`<option selected="selected">{!updatePicklstFldValsMap[updateObj.MFF_FieldName]}</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you can use `<apex:ouputPanel>` and rendered it without the value you want to display as selected (i.e picklist values not equal to select value in rendered condition) and outside the `<apex:repeat>` specify the value in the selected tag but make sure the empty value is not passed and it is made as selected

```
    <select Class="slds-input form-control" >
      <option value="">--None--</option>

         <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!len(updatePicklstFldValsMap[updateObj.MFF_FieldName]) >0 }">
            <option selected="selected">{!updatePicklstFldValsMap[updateObj.MFF_FieldName]}</option>
         </apex:outputPanel>

         <apex:repeat value="{!updateObj.MFF_RelatedFldval}" var="pickOpts"  >
           <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!pickOpts.value != updatePicklstFldValsMap[updateObj.MFF_FieldName]}">
             <option value="{!pickOpts.value}">{!pickOpts.label}</option>
           </apex:outputPanel>      
        </apex:repeat> 
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no way you can do it via standard repeat:

As you commented and it is also documented:

**HTML5 specifications**

https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-option-element

> The selected content attribute is a boolean attribute.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes :

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing white-space.

If any of the `option` elements contain `selected`word, it will be selected regardless of `value` corresponding to `selected` attribute.

The one option I see is to use `<apex:selectList` and `<apex:selectOptions>` tag instead of apex repeat and set the default value in controller binding field.

**Page**

```
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!bindingField}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

**Controller**

```
String bindingField = 'WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_BE_AS_DEFAULT_VALUE';
```

else, you can always use JavaScript.